# decrypt($this->getCcNumberEnc())?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

Magento 2.0.10
PHP 5.6.27

I created a Credit Card payment module (Save) which works very well.
The encryption feature seems to work correctly.

```
$info->encrypt($data->getDataByPath('additional_data/cc_number'))
```

but decrypt function always returns an empty field

in `Magento\payment\Model\info.php` line 76

```
public function getData($key = '', $index = null)
{
    if ('cc_number' === $key) {
        if (empty($this->_data['cc_number']) && !empty($this->_data['cc_number_enc'])) {
            $this->_data['cc_number'] = $this->decrypt($this->getCcNumberEnc());
        }
    }
    if ('cc_cid' === $key) {
        if (empty($this->_data['cc_cid']) && !empty($this->_data['cc_cid_enc'])) {
            $this->_data['cc_cid'] = $this->decrypt($this->getCcCidEnc());
        }
    }
    return parent::getData($key, $index);
}
```

idem in

```
$info->decrypt($info->getCcNumberEnc());
```

nothing.

Have you successful used the decrypt? It's a Bug ?

Comment: `$info->getCcNumberEnc()` returns the encrypted value?

Comment: yes, i use setCcNumberEnc($info->encrypt($data->getDataByPath('additional_data/cc_number'))) but I do not know if it's properly encrypted. Value 0:2:nU7lY00.... CCnumber 41111111.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Magento Bug !

in **quote_payment table**

cc_number_enc => datatype VARCHAR(255)

cc_ss_issue => datatype VARCHAR(255)
...

and in **sales_order_payment table**

cc_number_enc => datatype VARCHAR(32)

cc_ss_issue => datatype VARCHAR(32)

if you change VARCHAR(255) in sales_order_payment, this fix the problem